# Why did I fail this review audit when it was obviously off-topic?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

It's a question about an intermittant issue with a third-party site, the solution to which was "Well, it's back online now. I think it was just a server issue on their end".

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7252808

So, why did I fail this review audit?

Comment: *sighs* :) I feel with you. I try to get over it but if you have to wait a few weeks to get over it, it gets on your nerves :)

Comment: @shog9 I just failed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637146/monads-in-haskell-and-purity) which I thought was a no-brainer for being too broad.

Answer (score 20):

Because... No one voted to close it.

I've remedied this situation.

Got a better algorithm for selecting these audits being tested in Triage right now; hope to replace the one used for Close and Reopen audits soon.

Comment: Thanks, I felt mad when I got the "pay attention" message.

Comment: Aannnnnnnnd now it's a 0, so roomba will catch it.